# Searching for strings in txt file

Tags: python, string, split, txt

I have multiple .txt files and I'm looking for any of such strings: `lst = ['PASSED', 'FAILED', 'PASSED WITH WARNINGS']`
I crated code, but it splits on whitespaces and I get just `PASSED` instaead of `PASSED WITH WARNINGS`. How to correct my code?

```
for i in range(len(tab)):
    with open(tab[i], 'r') as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()
        var = [line for line in lines if (set(line.split()) & set(msgs))]
        print(var)
```

Example of my .txt file:

```
Some info here
Another info
Some more info
And so on...
2021_09_09_09_09_31     PASSED WITH WARNINGS
2021_09_09_09_09_34     PASSED WITH WARNINGS
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a short example for one of the .txt files you're parsing, and the expected output of that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = ['PASSED', 'FAILED', 'PASSED WITH WARNINGS']
for i in range(len(tab)):
    with open(tab[i], 'r') as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()
        var = [line.split(" ", 1)[-1].strip() for line in lines if any([word in line for word in lst])]
        print(var)
```

Comment: And how to leave only message PASSED WITH WARNINGS without the timestamp?

Comment: a hacky way would be:
`var = [line.split(" ", 1)[-1] for line in lines if any([word in line for word in lst])]`

Comment: But it leaves whitespace in front of PASSED WITH WARNINGS. Is there any way to delete this whitespace?

Comment: yes, apply a strip after it:

`var = [line.split(" ", 1)[-1].strip() ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)